# What are people replacing the missing C++/CLI Intellisense in VS 2010 with?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, intellisense

I'm about to start a project where I will be likely to use a lot of C++/CLI. I really miss C++/CLI Intellisense in VS 2010. I've heard of some Resharper-like products for C++, but wonder if they provide complete Intellisense. Do they also work with C++/CLI?

What are people doing to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com), a commercial addin for Visual Studio developed by Whole Tomato Software

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @gnat: Is that better?  Although I would think that the product name is the essential part of the answer, since that's what you'd search for if the link ever did break.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Visual Assist X does support C++/CLI because we make heavy use of it. Its a good product, give it a try. What it doesn't do, however is make browsing or F1 help work.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist is rumored to have IntelliSense support.  They don't advertise it, which is mighty strange.  Better try to eval version to check.

Other than that, I don't doubt that most devs replace the missing support in VS2010 with VS2008.