# Visual Studio C++/CLI 2010's Intellisense doesn't work; are there alternatives?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are people replacing the missing C++/CLI Intellisense in VS 2010 with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197034/what-are-people-replacing-the-missing-c-cli-intellisense-in-vs-2010-with)

I downloaded and installed Visual C++ 2010 Express, today.  To my shock and horror, a variable's dot was not followed with anything, an error at the bottom status bar reading:

"Intellisense: Unavailable for C++/CLI"

So... that being the case, is there an alternative to Intellisense that I can find and use?  Other stackoverflow questions addressed the possibly broken nature of Intellisense.  From what I've read, though:

- They suggest Visual Assist.  Visual Assist's free trial, as I just downloaded, is not compatible with VC++ 2010 Express.
- They talk about manipulating Visual C++ itself somehow, usually through the deleting of a .ncb file.  Do any of you know where this file is located?  If so, that's one answer I'm hoping for -- maybe it'll fix intellisense!

Thanks!  Of course, feel free to chime in with any other ideas!

Comment: I changed the tag and title, as C++ != C++/CLI.

Comment: Yes, there were similar entries that didn't seem to deliver.  I'm glad you could help with a practically-proven, free solution to this problem where other questions asked fell short.

Comment: Hmm... there seems to be a misunderstanding.  For the sake of future visitors: Visual Assist X was actually NOT the answer for me, as it doesn't work with VC++ 2010 Express (I couldn't install the trial).   Visual C++ 2008 Express turned out to be the (free) answer.  @Cody: You may be disregarding the non-Visual Assist X helpfulness available in the replies to my question.  Using myself as evidence, users will probably not find the "duplicate" question helpful for what I've asked.  :)  Perhaps you can edit your answer in there to include the VC++ 2008 download that works as a solution?

Comment: Update: Visual C++ 2010 will get Intellisense.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VS 2010 doesn't support C++/CLI Intellisense. The VS team promised it would come with an update, but I'm quite sure we won't see it. Too bad, C++/CLI is amazing for creating bridge classes between C++ and C#/VB/any other .NET managed laguage.

Visual Assist X indeed brings it back, but since VS Express editions don't support extensions, you have three options:

1) Live without Intellisense

2) Get VS Professional or better (if you are student, you can get it from MSDNAA for free)

3) Downgrade to Visual C++ 2008 Express

Comment: I was going to answer my own question but am glad to see you've listed the option that ended up working for me (option 3).  To add some complementary information, I obtained VC++ 2008 Express from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/.  Click the Visual Studio 2008 Express tab and Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition will be listed there.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

**Just use Visual Studio 2008.**

It's a simple matter of which feature you find more important. Pick only one:

- Multiple monitor support
- Intellisense for C++/CLI projects

Comment: VS 2010 has more new features than just multi-monitor support. .Net 4.0, real-time C++ syntax checks (irrelevant if OP uses CLI only though), better extension support (irrelevant in Express), box selection, C++0x features... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215.aspx